# Change style property in IE browsers only when resized below a certain width

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the flex property in IE only when the screen is resized below 600px. It works at full screen if I remove `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {` What must I do to target IE only when resized? How do you combine `min-width:0\0` with `max-width: 600px`?

```
/* IE9, IE10, IE11 */
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .flex-eqwidth {
            flex: none;
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it more specific for IE as your selectors. Cheers

```
@media only screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
                   and (max-width: 600px) {
        .flex-eqwidth {
            flex: none;
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }
    }
```